# Swift Collectionview Sections from a single array

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have an array of `IDs` `["one", "two", "three"...]`

These `Ids` are matched against a `json` I get from a `URLSession` and then displayed in a `collectionview`.
At the moment it's just one simple `collectionView` with the feature to reorder it by long press and drag.
But I need the possibilty to split it up in sections.

The best thing would be to make the sections dynamic, so that I can add as many sections as I want and then sort the cells into the sections.
I get what I could do if I had an array for every section like

`section1 = ["one", "two"]`

`section2 = ["three", "four"]`

But I have no Idea how to realize this in my current setup.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial on UICollectionView's by Raywenderlich.

Comment: This tutorial doesnt help very much. I'm familiar with a CollectionView but there are no sections added or data splitted up

Comment: `myArray = [["one", "two", "three", "four"]]` (one section). At some point `myArray = [["one", "two"], [ "three", "four"]]`. You retrieve `cellForRowAt:` `myObject = myArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`. numberOfSection: `myArray.count`. numberOfItemsInSections: `myArray[section].count`, in pseudo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it. I'm sure you could figure out a way to keep the single array, but don't. The maintenance nightmare will haunt you.

Create a view of the data which is broken into an array of arrays.

```
struct MySection {
    let sectionId: String // or whatever section metadata you need.
    let data: [Data] // or whatever your real type is.
}
```

In the collection view controller

```
var dataView: [MySection]
```

All the data in 1 section

```
self.dataView = [MySection(sectionId: "all data", data: self.data)]
```

Grouping the data into different sections

```
self.dataView = self.data.reduce([]) { dataView, datum in
    var dataView = dataView // make a mutable data view

    let sectionId = self.determineSectionIdFromDatum(datum) // <-- slotting into sections

    // Add into an existing section or into a new section
    if let index = dataView.index(where: { $0.sectionId == sectionId }) {
        let data = dataView[index].data + [datum]
        dataView[index] = MySection(sectionId: sectionId, data: data)
    } else {
        let data = [datum]
        dataView.append(MySection(sectionId: sectionId, data: data))
    }

    return dataView
}
```

At this point you will likely need to sort either the sections or the data within the sections.

Comment: That reduce function is fancy. +1

Comment: @Jeffery Thomas thanks for your suggestion. I think I have a bit of reading to do until I fully understand everything ;-)  First Problem I see is that my Array is at the moment stored in the UserDefaults, and this won't work with a Struct so I'll have to find a way around this

Comment: @theslash The type of `self.data` doesn't matter here. I used `[Data]` as a placeholder. It could be `[String]`, `[[AnyHashable: Any]]`, or whatever data type is returned by `UserDefaults`.